# MyApplication is never used

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to use the class "MyApplication". but I got messages such as my title. first of all, I added as (android:name = ".MyApplication"). and also added ( android:allowBackup="true"). but You can see my second screenshot. The Notice said MyApplication is an unresolved class... What should I do for resolving it?

[image]

[image]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application 
com.example.todolist.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't 
find class "com.example.todolist.MyApplication"
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.example.todolist.MyApplication" on path:/
```

Comment: Just do File>Invalidate Cache and Restart

Comment: @@Just do File>Invalidate Cache and Restart, thank a bunch.